# Two active colors in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

How to use two colors icons in BottomNavigationView?

```
<item android:color="@color/iconColorTrue" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/iconColor" android:state_checked="false" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/rv"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `selector` like the below .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" /> 
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

And use it with `itemIconTint` & `itemTextColor`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: Use state_enabled, paint all items in one color. And if state_checked, then you can paint only one item active

Answer (score -1):

Well maybe you simply are using the default icons in the layout that is why you are asking this question. You can replace the image (which is an `XML` file because it is a `vector asset` in the folder `@drawable`). You replace it with another colored vector asset and you are done. 
To add a new `vector asset` right click on the `drawable` folder and find `**add > new Vector Asset**`.

Comment: Tint is applied by the `BottomNavigationView` *after* all images are loaded so this won't work.

Comment: @EugenPechanec So do how can we set the tint color manually for every individual button?

Comment: Exactly, that's the question